# Staffing at the OSTP vs. Staffing of the OSTP

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do "Staffing at the OSTP" and "Staffing of the OSTP" share the same meaning? If so, are they interchangeable?

I have googled both "staffing at the office" and "staffing of the office", the latter turned out to have more cases. I am not sure whether the latter is natural in English.

> **Staffing at the OSTP** fell under former president Donald Trump to one-quarter of its previous level. Where does it stand now?
> I was sworn in this morning — I don’t actually know the precise number. But what I can say is the OSTP is hiring right now, and growing.
> Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01501-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not necessarily interchangeable since "staffing of the OSTP" would refer only to the OSTP's own staff, but "staffing at the OSTP" may include staffing that is not the OSTP's own staff, like staff on loan from other agencies, departments, offices, etc.; temps brought in through temp agencies who are actually the staff of those temp agencies and not the OSTP; interns who are either unpaid or not paid by the OSTP; and various others.

Working for the US government myself, I can tell you that government staffing is measured in full-time equivalents (FTEs) and only those who are actually employed full-time or part-time (each part-time employee's FTE being a fraction, whatever fraction of 2,080 hours they're scheduled to work in a year) by a given government agency, department, office, etc. are included in its staffing and staffing counts, are included in the number of FTEs on staff, not anyone else.

Whether journalist Eric Lander was being so precise with his language specifically concerning US government staffing and what it defines as "staffing," I can't say, but President Biden, a lifelong employee of the government, likely answered using the US government's working definition of "staffing" as it pertains to federal employment, though I'd have thought President Biden also would've said simply "OSTP," not "the OSTP," since government insiders don't ever use "the" before the acronym of an agency, department, office, etc., but then maybe President Biden was merely repeating back the journalist's own wording, adapting his message to his audience and recognizing that those outside the federal government do put "the" before such acronyms.

Comment: staffing of the OSTP?? staff of the OSTP

Answer (score -1):

It amazes me how every one turns to Google. What's wrong with a dictionary?

> "staffing at the office" vs "staffing of the office"

Both are correct when used with the word staff, however I would suggest that **"of" cannot normally directly follow staffing**. As an adjective it means "*relating to the staff*" ( relating to employees). As a noun it means "*the management of the number and types of workers needed in an organization*" Therefore

> a *shortage of staff* would be a *staffing shortage*

The usage of

> Staffing **at** the OSTP fell under former president Donald Trump

is correct, It regards staffing levels at that place.

Ref [How to use staffing](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/staffing.html)

---

**staffing; adjective** [ before noun ]; relating to the staff (= employees) of an organization

**staffing; noun** [ U ]   HR, WORKPLACE; the management of the number and types of workers needed in an organization:
Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/staffing?q=STAFFING)

---

staff at the office (at that place)

staff of the office (belonging to)